# RequestOption not working in Angular. What is the alternative for this

Tags: angular, typescript

I am very new to Angular. I am trying to use RequestOptions in my code, I know it's deprecated and we have other similar questions but answers to that question are not working in my case. So can some please help me? Below is my code which has RequestOption which is not working.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class AppHttpService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getHeaders() {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    // TODO: add token

    return headers;
  }

  getRequestOptions(): RequestOptions {
    const options = new RequestOptions();
    options.headers = this.getHeaders();

    return options;
  }

  get(url: string) {
    return this.http.get(url, this.getRequestOptions());
  }

  post(url: string, data: any) {
    return this.http.post(url, data, this.getRequestOptions());
  }

}
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
Error: src/app/services/app-http.service.ts:2:47 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http' or its corresponding type declara
tions.

2 import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What is the alternative code to achieve what I'm trying to do?

These are my configurations

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.11
Node: 14.3.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 11.2.12


Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.11
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.11
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.11
@angular/animation              4.0.0-beta.8
@angular/cdk                    11.2.11
@angular/cli                    11.2.11
@angular/material               11.2.11
@schematics/angular             11.2.11
@schematics/update              0.1102.11
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.1.5
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide your error

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to put that. I have updated it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already said, your way is deprecated, so I would recomment you to use the Angular HttpClient. As far as I now, the module `@angular/http` does not even exist anymore.And if I understand your question correctly, you want to add these headers to each request. So I have an example for you with the HttpClientModule and a HttpInterceptor. This is a common and easy way for doing that:

1. Import HttpClientModule and HttpInterceptors in your `app.module.ts`

   ```
   import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
   ```
2. Make a service for http requests

   Using the CLI generate a new service and declare methods for fetching data and sending requests. I would also recomment to not do it with an URL as parameter, but one method for each request, for example:

```
// Import HttpClient
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactService {

    // Declare baseURL
    private baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

    // Inject HttpClient in the constructor
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    // exmaple GET-request
    getMyContacts(userID: number): Observable<Contact[]> {
        return this.http.get<Contact[]>(`${this.baseURL}/contatcs/${userID}`);
    }

    // example POST-request
    newContact(email: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<any>(`${this.baseURL}/contacs/create`, {
            'email': email
        });
    }

}
```

3. Create a new TS file, something like `auth.interceptor.ts` with the following code. The interceptor will add the headers, you can specify as many as you want in the `setHeaders` object, to each request and you can also catch errors here globally if you want.

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TokenStorageService } from './../_service/_data/token-storage.service';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpErrorResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private tokenStorage: TokenStorageService
  ) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const request = this.addAuthHeader(req);

    return next
      .handle(request)
      .pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          return throwError(error);
        });
      );
  }

  addAuthHeader(req: HttpRequest<any>): HttpRequest<any> {
    return req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.tokenStorage.getToken()}`,
      }
    });
  }
```

4. Declare your interceptor in your `app.module.ts` in the providers array

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    }
  ]
```